# Git Interactive Rebase

Tags: git

I have a feature branch that has been a few months in the making. I've continually pulled from upstream/master to keep up-to-date and I've also regularly pushed to origin/feature_branch_name on bitbucket. My feature branch is now ready for a code review. Reviewers want 1 commit with all of my changes. I'm *kind of* familiar with interactive rebasing, but I'm not sure how to best accomplish this.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)**

Comment: One month of feature work and only one commit?

Comment: Lots of commits, but the code reviewers want 1 commit to review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier (and faster) to do a squashed merge instead:

```
$ git checkout -b tmp upstream/master     # Create a tmp branch (to do merging)
$ git merge --squash feature_branch_name  # Merge in feature_branch_name as one commit
$ git checkout feature_branch_name        # Switch to feature branch
$ git reset --hard tmp                    # Set tmp branch as feature_branch_name
$ git branch -d tmp                       # Delete tmp branch
$ git push -f                             # Push changes
```

Comment: You can squash all commits in an interactive rebase.